# Keepalived Virtual IP not responding to ARP requests Ubuntu 20.04 Server

Tags: server, 20.04, haproxy

I am not able to ping the virtual IP of keepalived. I checked and found that keepalived is not sending ARP requests or reply.

In my configuration, I have 2 servers, running on Ubuntu 20.04 with keepalived(2.0.19) :

controller1 : 192.168.2.14/24 and controller2 : 192.168.2.15/24. The IP is configured on both servers on eno2 interface. The goal is to configure Virtual IP 192.168.2.100/24 on the same physical interface.

This is my keepalived configuration on controller1 ( master)

```
vrrp_script chk_haproxy {      
  script "killall -0 haproxy"  # check if haproxy service is running
  interval 2                   # check every 2 seconds
  weight 15                    # add 15 points of priority if OK
}

vrrp_instance OS {
  interface eno2
  state MASTER
  virtual_router_id 1
  priority 100 # 100 on master, 90 on slave
  advert_int 1

  # minimum time interval for refreshing gratuitous ARPs while MASTER
  vrrp_garp_master_refresh 2
  vrrp_garp_master_refresh_repeat 2
  strict_mode off
  vrrp_garp_interval 0
  vrrp_gna_interval 0   
  vrrp_skip_check_adv_addr

#  use_vmac
#        vmac_xmit_base # Transmit VRRP adverts over physical interface

  unicast_src_ip 192.168.2.14 # ip of the instance
  unicast_peer {
   192.168.2.15 # ip of other instances, add more ip as necessary
  }

  authentication {
    auth_type PASS
    auth_pass keepaliveOS
  } 
    
  virtual_ipaddress {
    198.168.2.100/24 dev eno2
  }

  track_script {
    chk_haproxy
  }
}
```

This is my configuration on controller2

```
vrrp_script chk_haproxy {      
  script "killall -0 haproxy"  # check if haproxy service is running
  interval 2                   # check every 2 seconds
  weight 15                     # add 15 points of priority if OK
}

vrrp_instance OS {
  interface eno2
  state BACKUP
  virtual_router_id 1
  priority 90 # 100 on master, 90 on slave
  advert_int 1
  
  # minimum time interval for refreshing gratuitous ARPs while MASTER
  vrrp_garp_master_refresh 2
  vrrp_garp_master_refresh_repeat 2
  strict_mode off
  vrrp_garp_interval 0
  vrrp_gna_interval 0
  vrrp_skip_check_adv_addr
  
  unicast_src_ip 192.168.2.15 # ip of the instance
  unicast_peer {
   192.168.2.14 # ip of other instances, add more ip as necessary
  } 

  authentication {
    auth_type PASS
    auth_pass keepaliveOS
  }
    
  virtual_ipaddress {
    198.168.2.100/24
  }

  track_script {
    chk_haproxy
  }
}
```

1. Both servers are able to exchange VRRP advert packets and become master and slave.
2. If VIP address is configured manually on eno2, we are able to ping it.
3. `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1` and `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` settings have been done.
4. But when Virtual IP is configured through keepalive, it cannot be pinged from any server in the network including the MASTER. Running `tcpdump -i eno2 arp` does not show any ARP replies from the MASTER or SLAVE nodes.

What can be the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you allowed traffic specifically for the VRRP protocol?

> Physical routers within the virtual router must communicate within
> themselves using packets with multicast IP address 224.0.0.18 and IP
> protocol number 112.

(From WikiPedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Router_Redundancy_Protocol)

We had a similar issue that resolved when we allowed VRRP (protocol number 112) traffic between the nodes with KeepaLiveD services.